# Multipart identifier 'sys.tables' could not be bound

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I have the following SQL Query, trying to retrieve properties from my tables. It runs properly in a SQL Editor like in visual studio or SSMS.

```
USE UserList; 
SELECT sys.tables.name, value
FROM sys.tables, fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', N'table', DEFAULT, NULL, NULL)
WHERE sys.tables.name LIKE 'barn%';
```

but when I run it from my C# web app I get the error 'Multipart identifier 'sys.tables' could not be bound.' Can anybody show me what the issue is?

My C# code here is

```
string selectCommand = "USE UserList SELECT tables.name, value FROM sys.tables, fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', N'table', DEFAULT, NULL, NULL) WHERE tables LIKE '" + myTI.ToLower(User.Identity.Name) + "%';";
```

**UPDATE** when I remove the WHERE clause, this code works fine, even with sys.tables.name.

Comment: You might post your C# code as well.

Comment: `Where tables like` is wrong. Also you should use parametrized queries.

Comment: well... are you going to tell me why it is wrong?

Comment: Thought it was obvious. It should be `where tables.name like`. And if bobby tables signs up for the site their user name will cause a SQL Injection issue.

Comment: Oh yes I corrected that issue. Will look into parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the schema in the field list or `WHERE` clause, just the table name:

```
USE UserList; 
SELECT tables.name, value
FROM sys.tables, fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', N'table', DEFAULT, NULL, NULL)
WHERE tables.name LIKE 'barn%';
```

Comment: that gives me an error 'invalid column name 'tables'

Comment: Sounds like your query in C# is different- post your exact C# code as well.